# How database records deletion works internally?

Tags: database, b-tree

As far as I know when you run the DBMS, a B+ tree is load into RAM, working as a map storing the offsets from the files where the records are written (correct me if I am wrong).
What I want to know is: when a deletion occurs, what happens?

> The record (offset) is removed from the B+ tree, then when the DBMS
>   run again it delete all records from disk that are no longer in the B+ tree.

or

> The record is removed from the B+ tree, then from the disk storage

These are my thoughts

Comment: You might want to narrow down your question to a particular database, as they probably don't do it all the same way.

Comment: Answering your first assumption, not all engines load the entire tree into memory. Many will _cache_ data, but databases can be orders of magnitude larger than available RAM.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't want to know how a particular database works, but how generically a database works.

Comment: @DStanley So the records are directly stored in the tree?

Comment: As you can see, english is not my first language

Comment: No they are stored _on disk_. The index (tree) will be on disk as well and _might_ be in memory, but might be too big depending on the size of the database.  In any case, Tim is correct that different engines implement it differently.

Comment: There is no single sequence followed by all database engines for all tree sizes.  As written, there is no answer to your question.